# rebuild subversion repository after server failure

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I had an old SVN repo running on a Windows server 2003 with VisualSVN Server - the absolute path to the repo was stored on a NAS where it was backed up - however **not** using svnadmin /dump.  That 2003 server was decomissioned without dumping the repo, and now I need to get back to some of that codebase!

I still have the entact directory tree for the repo, and have built a new SVN server running on CentOS (and verified that it's working).  What is the best way to get projects out of the old repo into new source control?  If I lose history that's ok - I just need to get back to the 'current' files....and I can't use svnadmin /load (at least I don't think that will work)

Is it as easy as copying the dirtree into the new repo and using svnadmin /setuuid ?

Answer (score 5):

I got it - just thought I would post the answer for anyone else with the same problem.

I copied the root of my repository to the SVN root on my new server and ran `svnadmin recover <reponame>` and tada....I have my repos back.

I hope this helps anyone else in the same situation.